# AWK-- Replacing a field (element) value in a text file with a record (row) in another file

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have the following two text files:

A.txt

```
10000000 2.32 2737.373 272782
10000008 2.37 2837.292 239370
10000016 2.4  3028.237 289872
10000018 2.23 3110.227 289872
10000022 2.5  3228.222 289872
10000028 2.66 3325.11  28442
```

B.txt

```
10000016 10000000 10000028
10000008 10000018 10000022
```

What I need is to merge them like below (replacing fields' values of B.txt with the whole record in A.txt which its first field matches the field value in B.txt ):

```
10000016 2.4  3028.237 289872 10000000 2.32 2737.373 272782 10000028 2.66 3325.11  28442
10000008 2.37 2837.292 239370 10000018 2.23 3110.227 289872 10000022 2.5  3228.222 289872
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=a[$i]} 1' A.txt B.txt
10000016 2.4  3028.237 289872 10000000 2.32 2737.373 272782 10000028 2.66 3325.11  28442
10000008 2.37 2837.292 239370 10000018 2.23 3110.227 289872 10000022 2.5  3228.222 289872
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}`

  NR is the number of lines that we have read so far and FNR is the number of lines that we have read from the current file.  So, if `FNR==NR`, then we are still reading the first file (`A.txt`).  In that case, save each whole line, `$0`, into array `a` under a key equal to the first field, `$1`.   Then, skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=a[$i]}`

  For every field on this line, use the field as a key in array `a` and replace the field with its corresponding value in `a`.
- `1`

  This is cryptic awk shorthand which means print this line.